# Prepared statement with REGEXP_LIKE against OraOLEDB.ORACLE

Tags: c#, oracle, prepared-statement, sql-like

I have an odd situation. A prepared statement returns 0 rows, and the same statement when built out using string concatenation returns the expected 15 rows.

```
string mappingsTable = "MySchema.MyMappingsTable";
string sourceTablename = "Zone1_12345";
string destinTablename = "SurveyABC_result";
```

This one works and returns 15 rows

```
DataTable mappings = new DataTable();
OleDbCommand cmd = MyOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText 
  = "select * from " + mappingsTable 
  + " where regexp_like('" + sourceTablename + "', SourceNamePattern, 'i')"
  + " and UPPER(destinTablename) = UPPER('" + destinTablename + "')";

new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(mappings);
```

This one runs (no exceptions) and returns 0 zero rows !@#$%? Grr

```
DataTable mappings = new DataTable();
OleDbCommand cmd = MyOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText 
  = "select * from " + mappingsTable
  + " where regexp_like(?, SourceNamePattern, 'i')"
  + " and UPPER(destinTablename) = UPPER(?)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(sourceTablename, OleDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(destinTableName, OleDbType.VarChar));

new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(mappings);
```

Any ideas why the prepared statement gets no rows ?  I am at a loss :(

Comment: Probably, the Column is of `CHAR` datatype . You might need to use `RPAD(UPPER(?),your_column_length)` and the 2nd parameter to `regexp_like` is *different* ... _SourceNamePattern_ and _SmHeatLikePattern_ .... is it right?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are the values stored in `SourceNamePattern` and `SmHeatLikePattern` same? If they are holding different values then definitely both queries become different.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor overload of `OleDbParameter` that you have used takes as input the parameter name and parameter type. So basically you have missed passing the actual value. Change the code as shown below:

```
DataTable mappings = new DataTable();
OleDbCommand cmd = MyOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText 
  = "select * from " + mappingsTable
  + " where regexp_like(?, SmHeatLikePattern, 'i')"
  + " and UPPER(destinTablename) = UPPER(?)";

OleDbParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add(sourceTablename, OleDbType.VarChar);
param1.Value = sourceTablename;

OleDbParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add(destinTableName, OleDbType.VarChar);
param2.Value = destinTableName;

new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(mappings);
```